# Why is a block level element higher than the image it contains?

Tags: html, css

Without height specifications, a `<div>` (or a `<p>` or any other similar element) that contains only a single image is a bit higher than it. It looks like its 4px higher in Firefox and 5px higher in Chrome (according to Firebug and its chrome equivalent). The extra space is added under the image.

Obviously I can fix this by assigning a height to the div, but I'd like to understand why that space is there and wether there is a way to eliminate it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Image`  is inline level element thus it adheres to the line-height setting and it's being set at the baseline of the text by default.

If you will set the image to have `vertical-align: bottom` it will position the image at the descent line (very bottom of text line)

The other option is to set the image to `display: block` and skip all this inline gimmick

Answer (score 7):

Add to CSS:

```
img {display: block;}
```

By default `img` has `display:inline` thus all text line related stuff.

Comment: generally above switches to block for all images, if you want only specified - introduce class selector or relation to parent element

Answer (score 1):

Add `line-height: 0px;` to the **containing element**.

Setting the `img` to `display:block` also works but may break if someplace else you're hiding and showing images with `display:none` / `display:inline`.